# using mouseover/mouseout in gridview with alternating rows

Tags: asp.net, javascript, gridview, mouseover

I currently have a gridview with alternating colors, Silver and White, with a blue header (not selectable, obviously).  Initially, I had this onmouseover/onmouseout thing working but for some reason, yesterday morning it failed to work, and all day yesterday, I have been struggling, googling for answers and coming up short.  Here is the databound function:

```
protected void GridView_OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "onGridViewRowSelected('" + j.ToString() + "')");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "HighlightOn(this)");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "HighlightOff(this)"); 
        }
    }
```

And here is the onmouseover and onmouse out functions:

```
function HighlightOn(rowid)
{   
    if (document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId).disabled == false)
    {
        if ($(selectedIndex).val() != rowid.rowIndex)
        {
            rowid.style.backgroundColor = '#8FBAEF';
        }
    }
}

function HighlightOff(rowid)
{
    if (document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId).disabled == false)
    {   
        if ($(selectedIndex).val() != rowid.rowIndex)
        {
            var modIdx = rowid.rowIndex % 2;
            if (modIdx == 0)
            {
                rowid.style.backgroundColor = 'Silver';
            }
            else
            {
                rowid.style.backgroundColor = 'White';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

selectedIndex is being set by this:

```
function getSelectedRow(rowIdx)
{
    getGridViewControl(rowIdx);
    if (gridViewCtl != null)
    {
        $(selectedIndex).val(rowIdx);
        return gridViewCtl.rows[rowIdx];
    }
    return null;
}
```

This function just gets the row by giving it the id of the row in a gridview (used for the onclick event to change the color of the row).

The problem is this:  When I click on a row, it becomes highlighted.  When I then move the mouse, the other rows become somewhat highlighted, which is correct, but when I click on another row, and move the mouse out of that row, it becomes de-highlighted. And when i click on it again, does it stay highlighted.  selectedIndex is just a hidden field on the page.  Does anyone see why this doesn't function properly?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can solve this problem with some CSS (not supported in IE6):

```
tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

If I were to use JavaScript I would use an [unobtrusive technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Then you can skip the C#. Here is how you can do it:

```
$(function () {
  $("tbody tr")
    .mouseenter(function () {
      $(this).addClass("Highlight");
    })
    .mouseleave(function () {
      $(this).removeClass("Highlight");
    });
});
```

You need some CSS for this to work:

```
tbody tr.Highlight td {
 background-color: orange;
}
```